# выборка в input jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как вывести через переменную числовое значение того что написал пользоветель у input "Коли-во дополнительных углов" .За раннее спасибо)

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/5/

у меня получилось написать таблицу и выборку из выпадажищего списка. Не могу вспомнить как вывести числовое значение из инпута которое введет пользователь.Это последнее что хотел спросить у вас, выручите ребята.

Comment: @sasha1, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @sasha1 причем буквально с пол часа назад, вы задавали аналогичный вопрос.

Comment: decodeURI("%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9")+' '+ugol.value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документацию совсем не читаете ?

```
$("#ugol").val()
```

[Почитайте вот](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/)